# Eclipse/EGit Import From Local Git Repo?

Tags: eclipse, git, grails, egit

I can't seem to figure this out.  I keep importing, but I get no files from the repo.

I have a local repo that has a grails project that I checked in.  Now, I want to get those files out into a new project in eclipse.  (Using EGit).

I've tried several different ways, but all I ever get is an empty grails project.  I can see the source tree with all the sources in it in the git repo browser.

Help?

Comment: Is it an eclipse project?  If so, the Git Repository view has a "Import Projects" menu option that can be applied to your local repo.  If it was never an eclipse project to begin with, what does it look like on the file system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually do this:

- Import existing projects into Eclipse (could be you have to do some Import existing Grails project, depending on the plugin), and select the project directory (which also happens to be a Git repository)

*After your project is imported, Eclipse is still not aware of the Git repository*.

To fix this:

- Right-click the project
- Select Team -> Share
- Select Git in the next dialog
- Click Next a time or two, and you're done.