# How to separate my eclipse working directory to git repository directory working with egit?

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

How to separate my eclipse working directory (eclipse-workspace) to my git repository working directory  (git-workspace)?

Trying to use eclipse "Team" wizard to put my new java project java-hello-world under git source control (into a local directory repository named git-workspace), eclipse moves  the eclipse project (java-hello-world) from eclipse-workspace directory  to git-workspace directory.

I am working with Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.  Version: Oxygen.2 Release (4.7.2) Build id: 20171218-0600

I already installed:
 - Egit from - http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates
 - git version 2.16.0.windows.2

Answer (score 0):

One way is to (as [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11421028/6309)):

- Import the project into Eclipse (not EGit involved)
- check that your sources are still in place (and not copied into the Eclipse working tree)
- Then share your project with Git (EGit will recognize the existence if the Git repo):
  `Team -> Share / Git`.